# Guaranteed delivery IPC between C++ and Python

Tags: ipc, zeromq, distributed-computing, low-latency

I am working on building a C++ proxy for forwarding network packets for our upstream Python application, and I am looking for a performant and reliable solution for communicating between the proxy and the application.

From what I read on the internet, ZeroMQ seems to be a good solution from a performance perspective. But it does not support guaranteed delivery. Just wondering if there is a good IPC library that fit my requirements, or if there is a way to use ZeroMQ in a hacky way to avoid packet loss?

Answer (score 1):

### Without drilling down to details, there are two aspects:

Yes, ZeroMQ will give you a wealth part of both, but do not expect it to be a one-liner ( while the python may be quite a close to that ). The Real-time part that is more sensitive -- C++ part -- may be smart and light-weight so as to take minimum resources and care in your `[proxy]`-engine side and the up-stream python will benefit from the separation and can enjoy all the feature-rich post-processing tasks.

**Performance** - ZeroMQ is devilish good for messaging. That said, one may forget about *packet* and rather start thinking in terms of **a-behaviour-related signalling** which gives developers a lot of power for our main jobs. With all written down below, one may wish to also check another smart-messaging framework from Martin Sustrik ( a co-father of ZeroMQ ) - a nanomsg which may provide you even better fits for signalling-behaviour patterns for your direct and fast `IPC`-signalling project ( guess all developers will love the [in-built FSA engines](http://250bpm.wdfiles.com/local--files/blog:25/events3.png) rather than tweaking the threads/raw-socks/`IPC`-channels ).

**Reliability** - ZeroMQ is a very powerful horse for heterogeneous ( many ports allowing any-to-any message-passing, be it Python, Erlang, C++, Go alongside the content-processing path), massively distributed, almost ( within all reasonable range ) linear scaleable solutions.

**Guaranteed delivery** is a thing ZeroMQ philosophy strives to avoid ( and with all the wisdom lets it to the Application's own domain for context-aware handling ).

### With a deeper look down into details, there is a nice `IPC` exception:

For an `IPC`-transport class, there is no place to lose content. In case you setup your ZeroMQ infrastructure right on both ends of the `IPC`-transport connected signalling channel, there is no chance for a data-loss. You may fine tune Zero-COPY mode with your end-points' buffer-allocation(s) / data-manipulation steps for further shaving a few more usec from the fact, your data is already stored in memory and need not get copied to have it passed via `IPC`.

If under a real pressure to cut even more, check the [nanomsg for going a step farther](http://nanomsg.org/documentation-zeromq.html) ( at a cost of not so wide co-developed wrappers, which is no trouble for your project as defined above ).